# Django QuerySet filter in with a given sorted list

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to sorted person order_by reputation which is in Model Membership. Just like this:

```
person_ids = Membership.objects.all().order_by('-reputation').values_list('person_id', flat=True)
persons = Person.objects.filter(id__in=person_ids) # Such as [3, 1, 2]
```

But the results QuerySet is not the correct order, **SQL IN** is a no order search.

I want the result persons is a queryset, so i don't want to list persons and order them with
sorted function.

What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a double underscore in the parameter, like this:

```
Person.objects.order_by('-membership__reputation')
```